# How to configure nginx drupal virtual host to use varnish

Tags: nginx, varnish

I've configured a drupal website using nginx and the following declaration:

```
server {
listen 8080;
listen 443 ssl http2;
server_name site.dev;
root "/home/Code/site";
```

Inside /etc/varnish/default.vcl i have the following config values:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}
```

Now the problem i'm having is that accessing the website via site.dev is impossible, i'm forced to use :8080 now, when i thought varnish would take over all requests at port 80? All pages being served are also (not surprisingly) not being served via varnish.

My daemon used to start vanish looks like this:

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a 127.0.0.1:80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,256m"
```

Any pointers to how i can set this up most welcome. Thanks

Comment: First of all what OS are you using? Then on wich port is varnish listening? You can configure varnish to listen on port 80 and then server the requests from nginx which is listening on port 8080 on localhost host or a private ip etc

Comment: Plesae share the command line used to start your varnish daemon (or /etc/varnish/varnish.params).

Comment: @BogdanStoica i'm using Linux Ubuntu 16.04, via Homestead (laravel vagrant box).

Comment: @BenjaminBaumann i've updated the question with daemon options

Comment: What's the output of varnishlog when you test your site on port 80 (via curl for example)?

Comment: @BenjaminBaumann it shows nothing. actuallly port 80 stops working if i configure my virtual host to listen on 8080 (which is the part where i thought varnish would handle)

Comment: OK and if you stop nginx, start varnish and make the same test? I suspect nginx to hold the port 80 so that varnish cannot take it. Alternatively you can  run netstat -tulpn | grep :80 to see which process listent on port 80.